# Can we have a custom color of question background for watched tags?

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

Can we have a custom color of question background for watched tags so that it is easy to recognize question (by tag)?

For example, I am watching two tags. The background of question containing first tag could be light blue and that of other could be light green.

[image]

In the above screenshot, the color (on *SO*) of watched tag is orange type. I would like to change it

Comment: You could use a userscript or similar addons to change it yourself, see e.g. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7845/36296

Comment: What happens when you have like 20 different tags you're following?