# Confusing background color in question list

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, user-interface

I am not sure if this is new or I just haven't been paying attention, but a number of questions have a sort of peach (or whatever) background color in the question list and sidebar, e.g. on Stack Overflow:

[image]

The problems are:

- I can't tell what this signifies.

  - I thought maybe it meant "unread" but visiting the question doesn't clear the background.
  - When I refresh the page, sometimes questions randomly go from peach to white.
- The low contrast with the section header background in "highlighted" questions on the right sidebar is visually unfortunate.
- Maybe it's just my monitor† / eyes, but it's almost identical to the color of deleted posts, and it's shorting out my brain when I look at the list:

  [image]

So this post is a combination question and feature request:

- What are these highlighted backgrounds supposed to signify?
- Can you make them be a more distinguishable color, or use some other indicator besides background color (for whatever is being indicated)?
- Can you somehow find a way to make the meaning of these indicators more apparent?

---

<sup>† Fwiw, I've got Chrome's color profile forced to [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB), and my monitor is calibrated and in sRGB mode.</sup>

Comment: The "peach" type background color are for questions with one of your watched tags (e.g., the first one has "C++" and the next 2 have "Java", with both tags showing as ones you're watching).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Ah ha, thank you. Personally, I don't find that useful, since I can use a filter to draw attention to watched tags instead, but now I can see they have the `s-post-summary__watched` class set, so I can resolve it with a custom stylesheet.

Comment: FYI, a couple of closely related questions are [Can we have a custom color of question background for watched tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316525/562482) and [Change shade color for watched tags on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319494/562482).

Comment: Cross-site duplicate of [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281740/4642212).

Comment: You know this colour has been around since forever, right? It was only gone for a couple of days because of the redesign of the home page.

Comment: @Luuklag Yeah I'm not sure; I have rarely checked the SO front page in the last few years. If it popped up [circa 2018](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/319503/230261) I probably wouldn't have seen it. Or I'm just stupid, lol (more likely). *Shrug*

Answer (score 1):

Well, in the meantime, if anybody's trying to hack it with custom CSS:

- The highlighted question list items have class `s-post-summary__watched`.
- The sidebar background is unrelated, but defined in `s-sidebarwidget__yellow`.

E.g. I put this one together (I copied the watched icon from the tag elements):

```css
.s-post-summary__watched {
    background-color: initial;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='14' height='14' viewBox='0 0 14 14'%3E%3Cpath d='M7.05 1C2.63 1 0 6.5 0 6.5S2.63 12 7.05 12C11.38 12 14 6.5 14 6.5S11.37 1 7.05 1ZM7 10.17A3.59 3.59 0 0 1 3.5 6.5 3.6 3.6 0 0 1 7 2.83c1.94 0 3.5 1.65 3.5 3.67A3.57 3.57 0 0 1 7 10.17Zm0-1.84c.97 0 1.75-.81 1.75-1.83S7.97 4.67 7 4.67s-1.75.81-1.75 1.83S6.03 8.33 7 8.33Z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 14px 14px;
}

.s-sidebarwidget__yellow {
    background-color: hsla(47,87%,94%,0.1); /* --yellow-050 + alpha */
}
```

[Styleworld publish link](https://userstyles.world/style/3134/stack-overflow-gentler-highlight).

It can be applied with your user CSS manager of choice (I use Stylus on Chrome). Makes it look like:

[image]

I just went quick and dirty with the eyeballs ¯\*(ツ)*/¯.

And now that I look at them, they're not even that useful, really, because the eyeballs in the tag icons are already pretty visible. You could comment them out of the CSS.